# How should I define 'static' subroutines in Perl?

Tags: function, perl, oop, package, static-methods

I'm used to work in Java, so perhaps this question is a Java-oriented Perl question... anyway, I've created a `Person` package using `Moose`.

Now, I would like to add a few subroutines which are "static", that is, they do not refer to a specific `Person`, but are still closely related to `Person` package. For example, `sub sort_persons` gets an array of `Person` objects.

In Java, I would simply declare such functions as `static`. But in Perl... what is the common way to do that?

**p.s.** I think the Perlish terminology for what I'm referring to is **"class methods"**.

Comment: @FM that's was exactly my line of thought. See my comment to eugene y :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's no such thing as a static method in Perl. Methods that apply to the entire class are conventionally called *class methods*. These are only distinguished from *instance methods* by the type of their first argument (which is a package name, not an object). Constructor methods, like `new()` in most Perl classes, are a common example of class methods.

If you want a particular method to be invoked as a class method **only**, do something like this:

```
sub class_method {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    die "class method invoked on object" if ref $class;
    # your code        
}
```

Comment: +1 I just "found" about it myself :) I guess the most common example is  `new()` which I never thought of in terms of 'static' but it obviously is.

Comment: Unless there's some reason why it would be bad for the class method to be called on an object, I would just skip checking `ref $self`.

Comment: To help distinguish class methods from object methods, I like to use `$class` as the variable that holds the invocant.  So `sub class_method { my ($class, @params) = @_; # blah }`

Comment: @cjm skipping the `ref` check, means you may end up with the args in `$class` instead, so will still need a check to split them out.

Comment: @Deanna, I was referring to calling it as `$object->class_method(@args)` instead of `Class->class_method(@args)`.  That seems to be what the `ref` is trying to prevent, and it's often overkill.  The only way you get the first arg in `$class` is calling it as a subroutine (`class_method(@args)`), and the `ref` check doesn't prevent that unless the first argument is normally a reference.

Comment: @cjm maybe we're calling it differently, but the first argument is the parameters when not calling it with `$self`. They all shift down 1.

Comment: @Deanna, there are two different ways to call a method in Perl.  You can call it on an object of that class (`$object->method(@args)`) or on the class itself (`Class->method(@args)`).  In both cases, the first argument to the method will be the thing to the left of the `->` arrow, either a blessed reference (`$object`) or a plain string (`'Class'`).  The `ref` test prevents you from calling the method using an object of the class instead of the class name.  There's often no good reason to prevent that.

Comment: @cjm I tend to use `class::method` which doesn't do as you say. The first argument is `@args`, not a class name or reference.

Comment: @Deanna, `class::method` is a plain function call, not a method call, which is why it doesn't provide an implicit first argument.  But this answer isn't about function calls, and the `ref` check doesn't help you distinguish between calling a class method and calling that same sub as a plain function (unless the first explicit argument is always a reference).